# How to capture Informatica system failure error

Tags: informatica

I have a requirement where I need to capture Informatica system failure error and load the same into database. Any suggestions to access the system failure error and pass it to another mapping through a variable
EX: session failed due to source file path is wrong, i need to capture that error

Comment: basically i want to get the error reason from session log and store it in a variable. My informatica is on windows server. What command task script can fetch the error from the log file

Answer (score 0):

A system failure would be the Powercenter service or server is down, so I assume you just mean session failure?  A session failure is returned through its workflow variable $session_name.Status.  If you need to pass that into a mapping for some reason you would assign that to a mapping parameter or variable in its pre-session variable assignment in its session.